# Get number of arguments for a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, arguments

I would like to get the the number of arguments required for a stored procedure in MySql. Is that possible?

My first thought was to try

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.ROUTINES;
```

but therein lies no information about the number of arguments as far as I can see. Next try was

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

but that just seems to return a subset of the first query.

My goal is to be able to "NULL-pad" a sproc call in PHP to avoid errors like

```
"Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE schema.table; expected nn, got mm
```

To make a static lookup table would of course work, but is certainly not desireable. And sure, one could parse the message returned, alter the query and retry, but that does not seem very nice either.

Thanks in advance! /Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the parameter list via:

SELECT DISTINCT 
     name, 
     param_list 
FROM 
mysql.proc 
     WHERE db=DATABASE();

Comment: Thanks! Still a bit awkward format, but at least all info is there and parsable. Shame it's only as well-formed as the string used to create the procedure (IN/OUT/INOUT can be omitted for example) though.

Answer (score 0):

SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure_name>;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately the statement seems to have two drawbacks. 1: It returns the _entire_ procedure - a good deal of parsing is required and a lot of unnecessary data. 2: It requires you to be the creator of the function, otherwise the "Create Procedure" part is null and no information can be extracted.

Thanks anyway! /Victor